# &q - &p, q and p pointing to non-initialised char array. And o/p is 1. How?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, pointer-arithmetic, ptrdiff-t

```
main(){
    char a[20],*p,*q;
    p=&a[0];
    q=&a[10];
    printf ("%d\n",&q - &p) }
```

This C program gives o/p as:

```
1
```

As I understand, the values stored at those addresses are garbage. How can their subtraction be 1?

Can anyone please explain how?

Comment: You are subtracting the addresses of p and q, not their contents.

Comment: You should probably edit your question to explain what *you* expect and why.

Comment: It has nothing to do with initialised arrays, but the placement of `p` and `q` on the stack. They must be adjacent here, but they don't have to be.

Comment: `q` and `p` are two different pointers. They are not two different elements of the same array (of pointers).  Therefore `&q - &p` is subtracting two pointers that do not point to elements of the same array (nor one past its end), and so the behavior is undefined.  Note that what `q` and `p` themselves point to is entirely irrelevant; the array `a` has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Did you mean `*q - *p`? That would make more sense in the context. But even so, it could be anything, without any reason worth looking into.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Subtracting the addressee gives 10. Because they are 10 chars apart.

Comment: No, subtracting the addresses would be `q - p`.

Comment: No, the addresses are the addresses of p and q which can be anywhere.  The contents of p and q, which are pointers in this case, are themselves addresses inside the array.  Get rid of the `&` address-of unary operator and you'll get the results you expect.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons yes, removing the & sign results to 10. But with the & sign I expected it'd be some garbage value.

Comment: @spiders.here "But with the & sign I expected it'd be some garbage value" which is exactly what you got.

Answer (score 1):

`q` and `p` are two different pointer variables. They are not two different elements of the same array (of pointers).  Therefore `&q` and `&p` are two pointers (to pointers) that do not point to elements of the same array (nor one past its end).  Therefore evaluating `&q - &p` causes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), and it is not possible to use the language definition to reason about what may or may not happen beyond that point.

See also [Is subtraction of pointers not pointing to different elements of same array valid in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673084/is-subtraction-of-pointers-not-pointing-to-different-elements-of-same-array-vali).

What *might* be happening in your program is that `q` and `p` happen to be allocated at adjacent addresses on the stack, with `q` at a higher address than `p`, and that the compiler implements `&q - &p` by subtracting their actual addresses and dividing by their size.  That would account for a value of 1.  But the compiler is in no way obliged to do this; it could, in principle, instead print `47` or `BUG` or delete all your files.

Note that what `q` and `p` themselves point to is entirely irrelevant; the array `a` has nothing to do with your code as it stands.

You may have been thinking of doing `q-p` instead.  That would be subtracting pointers to two different elements of the `a` array.  It is perfectly well defined, and the result would be 10.

(By the way, the result of subtracting two pointers has type `ptrdiff_t`.  You are using the printf specifier `%x` which is only valid for an argument of type `unsigned`; this causes undefined behavior as well.  The correct format specifier would be `%td`.)

Comment: Pardon me if I'm incorrect. Here p is pointing to 0th element, and q is pointing to 10th element. Isn't that pointing to the elements of the same array?

Comment: @spiders.here: Yes, and therefore evaluating `q-p` would be just fine.  But that's not what you do; you evaluate `&q - &p` which is completely different.  That is, `q` is a pointer to an element of the `a` array.  But `&q` is a pointer to the variable `q` which is not itself in an array at all.

Comment: I corrected the specifier to %d. And I guess I understand the result. Thanks

Comment: @spiders.here: `%d` is still wrong as `ptrdiff_t` is not the same as `int`.  It really must be `%td`, or else you need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

This call

```
printf ("%x\n",&q - &p);
```

have undefined behavior because the pointer expressions `&p` and `&q` do not point to elements of the same array. That is the expression `&p` has the type `char **` and points to the variable `p` while the expression `&q` having the same type `char **` points to the variable `q`.

It seems you mean

```
printf ("%tx\n",q - p);
```

In this case the output will be hexadecimal value of 10 `a`.

Or if you will write

```
printf ("%#tx\n",q - p);
```

then the output will be

```
0xa
```

Comment: @NateEldredge You are mistaken. The length modifier t can be used with the conversion specifier x provided that the outputted value is not negative,

Comment: Is there a citation for that?  The `t` length modifier is supposed to take an argument of type "`ptrdiff_t`
or the corresponding unsigned integer type".  By analogy with the other length modifiers, I presume this means "... depending on whether a signed or unsigned conversion specifier is being used".  So `%tx` would need an argument whose type is the unsigned integer type corresponding to `ptrdiff_t` (which doesn't have a standard name AFAIK) but not `ptrdiff_t` itself.

Comment: @NateEldredge "5 The values of any padding bits are unspecified.54) A valid (non-trap) object representation of a signed integer type where the sign bit is zero is a valid object representation of the corresponding unsigned type, and shall represent the same value." and  (function calls) "— one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the
corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The passage you quoted, from C 2018 6.5.2.2 6, does not apply to calling `printf`, possibly unless the program has declared it itself without including `<stdio.h>`. That paragraph applies when the expression used to call the function does not include a prototype, but `<stdio.h>` declares `printf` with a prototype. Later sentences subdivide this into cases where the function is defined with or without a prototype, but how the function is defined is separate from the type of the expression used to call it,…

Comment: … and the passage you cite applies to the subcase in which the function is defined without a prototype, which we do not know to be true (it is an implementation detail).